# Most efficient way to provide unique Refresh Token

Tags: jwt, basic-authentication, refresh-token

I am using refresh tokens with access tokens for authentication. There is a small chance that refresh tokens may conflict each other and thats cause problem. I know i can make unique constaint for refresh tokens in my table but thats cause lots of operation for database. I head second way as GUID but i am not sure. What do you think ?

Comment: I think, you put your users privacy at a high risk. A refresh token must be unique and should have cryptographically randomness. GUID is not. The computational costs for creating crypto random values are minimal and do not cause any problem with your database.

Comment: It is minimal to have cryptographically random refresh tokens but isn't making them unique in database causes a performance issue when there is lot of rows in refresh token table?

Comment: With crypto random values and sufficient bits you have a very, very small chance to get duplicates. You can make the math yourself: 2^bits. Refresh tokens will be send from a client relatively infrequent because access tokens have usually expiration durations from 5min to hours. Usually you use an index in your database, and caching in memory will not hurt as well. I wouldn't implement such a system myself but use an existing Open Source solution.

Comment: I am currently not using unique column constaint in my database, i creating random refresh token and using that token to refresh access token like usual. You are right about the possibilities of collasions but even a little chance make me worry about security so i don't know if i check database for collasions before i create the refresh token or not. Because this causing performance issues. And i am using index on refresh token like you point it out. Waiting for your advices, thanks.

Comment: So, the question is basically: should we verify crypto random values of n bits for uniqueness in the db when creating them. There are pros and cons. I would do it and use a fast method to check it. So, this boils down to the question, what is the best storage and index to accomplish this on your database, certainly something in-memory, hash based. If it turns out, _after profiling_, that your database is too slow, a dedicated storage like Redis or memcached might help here.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL and indexing refresh token's token column. Redis might be a good choice but this idea came to my mind thinking about it, is it really efficient to use some memory based storage to check some data exist in database? because most of the time(maybe 99.9%) there won't be any token matching with the token i sent to check and redis would have to look for my database(postgresql) because it works like this? with this logic redis or any memory based storage doesn't look a good idea for this stiuation. What do you think?